# Cant find where the memory leak is in this short piece of code

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management

I have an app which is running a simple timer. The following code is run several times per second from an NSTimer. I'll be the first to admit that memory management is my weakest skill right now as a new iOS developer. When I run this code, if i leave the timer running for a while, i start to get get memory warnings, and eventually it crashes. If i disable the NSTimer, it runs fine for hours. I cant see what is causing the leak:

```
- (void)onTimerTick
{

    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

    NSCalendar *calendar= [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]; 
    NSCalendarUnit unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit; 
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date]; 

    NSInteger hour = [dateComponents hour]; 
    NSInteger min = [dateComponents minute]; 
    NSInteger sec = [dateComponents second];      


    double milliSince1970 = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
    int secsSince1970 = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
    int frame = (((milliSince1970 - secsSince1970) * 1000) / frameDuration) + 1;


    timeCode.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d:%d:%d", hour, min, sec, frame];
    [calendar dealloc];

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Call `[calendar release]`, not `dealloc`... the framework calls `dealloc` for you when `calendar` no longer has anything retaining it.

Comment: Oh you hero. Thanks a lot - its working perfectly and I've learned that I've been deleting objects wrong all this time! Thanks.